# How to show interest in an recently opened managerial position in my company

Tags: resignation, promotion

- I just joined a company (4 months ago)
- I am doing pretty well, lots of positive feedbacks since then
- The head of our department just resigned and there's no interim/direct replacement (or it has not been announced yet)
- I believe I can take the responsibility and do her job very well

How can I suggest to my managers that I'm interested in this position?

Comment: You walk up to your managers and say "I'm interested in this position"

Comment: Gotta get the balls to do it :)  thanks dan.  But I am looking for more an email type of solution

Comment: @DanPichelman I would agree, it's as simple as communicating interest. You should post this as an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### State your interest outright, in a clear and concise manner, preferably in person, face to face.

> I understand that JOAN recently retired, leaving a vacancy in JOAN'S
>   POSITION.  I know I have only been with the company for four months,
>   but I believe I can take on that responsibility and do the job well. 
>   Will there be a formal process for hiring a new JOAN'S JOB TITLE?  If
>   so, I would greatly appreciate an opportunity to apply.

I would shy away from emails, as they are impersonal and can be ineffective, but sometimes they are the only option.  If you don't work in the same building as the hiring manager, a phone call would be better than an email, but don't leave a voicemail if you don't get an answer.  Wait and call back again later.

From my perspective there is nothing to be lost in asking.  Best case scenario you get a promotion.  Worst case scenario you get denied, but management understands that you have an interest in moving up.

**You've got nothing to lose.**

Comment: Thank you , @Lumberjack
I believe many will benefit from this template. After sending out an email based on your suggestion, I Skyped with my manager and they are considering me for the role. You really helped me.

Comment: @Dan I'm glad to hear it.  Good luck!